# MS SQL Server is accessible locally but not over the internet

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to access a named instance of Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 SP2 on the local network, I have no problem. But when access it outside office from the internet, I can not connect to the database server.

It send back the "famous" following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

This error happen in the winforms application and through the SQL Server Management studio.

The server instance name is correct since I can use it on the same local network. I precised that the server is a domain name such as "sql2008.domainname.com\sqldbname".
I also make sure to configure SQL Server to allow remote connections from the SSMS > Server Properties > Connections > Remote connections.

More precisions: SQL Browser is up and running. TCP/IP enabled. No problem when installing the database server.

I did a lot of research the last few days and tried everything... I do not have any more ideas.

The system administrator responsible for this server assure me that the ports 1433 and 1434 are open on the database server. I can ping the server from home and when i use putty the command telnet host port I got no error. The command is waiting for me to type something.

Do you have any other ideas that may cause this problem? Port forwarding, etc?

Thank you,
LB

Comment: How are you connecting to your office network? Please tell me you're using a VPN connection!

Comment: Named instances do not always run on port 1433. UDP port 1434 is used for port discovery. Are you certain this instance is running on 1433?

Comment: Are you running with Dynamic ports?

Comment: @Chris McKeown: Actually I am testing it on a production server for the moment.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer yes, sqlbrowser.exe run on the port 1434. Should I use this parameter instead of 1433?

Comment: @KingyCronus I left Dynamic ports blank and set the port as 1433 since the system admin told me he only opened 1433 and 1434 for testing at the moment.

Comment: @LudoB What I'm getting at is whether your SQL server is exposed directly to the Internet with no VPN or rules to restrict access. If I knew your SQL server's IP address, could I connect to port 1433 from my machine?

Comment: @LudoB I'm not a SQL Server expert. I just know that the default instance uses 1433 by default, making it unavailable for named instances. Microsoft [KB 823938](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938) explains how it all works much better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

We had some weird network issues after applying SQL 2008 R2 SP2.

There is already a Cumulative Update 1 for it that includes 35 hotfixes.

**Cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2720425

You may want perform a packet capture as the amount of data to reproduce the issue is quite low and the issue is easily reproducible.  The SQL parsers for NetMon are actually quite good.

Comment: OK, thank you Greg for your input, I will try to apply the update package 1 tomorrow. I downloaded also Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4. Will keep you updated.

Comment: I changed nothing and it's working today according to another tester. I do not really know what happen, I sent an email to the system admin to ask some more clarifications. Will keep you updated if I found out what was causing the error.